# How to share a Set<AnyCancellable>?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a `Set<AnyCancellable>` that is tied to the user's session. Any subscriptions tied to the user session get added to this set. I'd like to be able to pass this set around so other things can tie their logic to the user's session. The issue I'm having is that Set is struct that passing it via `inout` won't really work. Is there a better way to share a `Set<AnyCancellable>`?

Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
class UserManager {
  private var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable>

  init(cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable>) {
    self.cancellable = cancellable
  }
}

class UserFeedManager {
  private var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable>

  init(cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable> {
     self.cancellable = cancellable
  }
}

let cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let userManager = UserManager(cancellable)
let userFeedManager = UserFeedManager(cancellable)

// ... Later, once the user signs out, clean up any work 
// started by the UserManager or the UserFeedManager
cancellable.forEach { $0.cancel() }
cancellable.removeAll()
```

Comment: "I'd like to be able to pass this set around so other things can tie their logic to the user's session." Could you explain what that means?

Comment: have you tried putting it in a central location?

Comment: Added an example of what I'd like to do

Comment: @loremipsum my current solution is to stick the set in a class and pass that around. I was wondering if there was something better that could be done

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of Combine subscriptions is bound to the `AnyCancellable` returned by the subscription. So if the last reference to your `Set<AnyCancellable>` is released, all `AnyCancellable`s stored in the `Set` will also be released and hence all subscriptions will be cancelled.

So instead of passing in the `Set<AnyCancellable>` from the outside and manually calling

```
cancellable.forEach { $0.cancel() }
cancellable.removeAll()
```

, you should simply expose the `Set` on your `UserManager` and whenever your user signs out, just ensure that you deallocate the previous `UserManager` object and create a new one. This will ensure that all previous subscriptions were cancelled automatically.

```
class UserManager {
  var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
}
```

This way, you just need to pass around the same `UserManager` instance until the user is logged in and create and destroy the instance when the user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend instead to inject a protocol, like

```swift
protocol CancellablesHolder {
    func add(cancellable: AnyCancellable)
}
```

and have `UserManager` conform to that protocol:

```swift
class UserManager {
    private var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable>
}

extension UserManager: CancellablesHolder {
    func add(cancellable: AnyCancellable) {
        cancellable.add(cancellable)
    }
}
```

With the above defined, you can

```swift
class UserFeedManager {
  private var cancellablesHolder: CancellablesHolder

  init(cancellablesHolder: CancellablesHolder) {
```

This way, you keep the implementation details hidden from the clients of `CancellablesHolder`, and you also transparently pass the `UserManager` along the road, without exposing to client which don't necessarily care about the actual type.

This results in reduced coupling, and flexibility in implementing the storage of the cancellables, as the consumers don't know, and don't care about the storage mechanism.